# What may let cloning from a Gitlab repo into Qt Creator fail?

Tags: git, qt, gitlab, qt-creator

I've been following [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-vcs-gitlab.html) guide in the Qt Creator manual to connect my gitlab repo with Qt Creator for Windows. Following the steps under "Cloning Projects" works just fine until I click on "Clone" when it says "Cloning failed.".

In my lack of understanding I've tried both an access token for the specific project and my account, made the project both private and public, tried both the git@ and https Repository option, tried a different project, an empty project, a project with the exact directory Qt creates and a project with just the Qt files.

Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Can you tell us the settings you tried? Did you create the access token with appropriate scopes?

Comment: @sytech As for the settings of the token I've selected all scopes just in case and set the expiration date for in a year. Within Qt Creator I chose an appropriate host (can't add a host if it's the wrong format) and left the port on 443 and HTTPS on ticked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was previously using Github with Atom for version control, which I didn't need Git for, the problem was that I hadn't had Git installed.